# dynamically coloring <td>'s based on mysql retrieved values

Tags: php

I need to generate a simple table with dynamically coloured `<td>`'s based on mysql retrieved values.

Here is what I need:

```
$target = 20;
$achieved = 13;
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
echo "<td></td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

The above code plots a table with no of `<td>`'s equal to `$target`. All I need is then to color the background of these `<td>`'s with the value inside variable `$achieved`. So in this case I want 13 colored `<td>`'s.

Comment: I don't see any "mysql values" here

Comment: the mysql values are $target and $achieved

Comment: So if the value INSIDE the `td` is `$achieved`, then the background is different?

Comment: actually the first loop is to generate dynamic no of td's equal to $target and i want only those no of td's colored as the $achieved value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try this, and add a `td.coloured` on your css

```
$target = 20;
$achieved = 13;
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
    if ($i < $achieved) {
        echo "<td class=\"coloured\"></td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Did you mean \"coloured\" ? :) Or even echo '..."colorured"...'?

Comment: @Jasper thanks for your comment, I correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a standard `if` statement here, something similar to:

```
if ($i < $achieved) // do the color
```

Inside the loop, you can populate a `$bgcolor` variable and then append that into the `<td>` you're outputting:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
    $bgcolor = '';
    if ($i < $achieved) {
        // give it a red background color
        $bgcolor = ' bgcolor="#ff0000"';
    }

    echo "<td" . $bgcolor . "></td>";
}
```

If you want more advanced styles, I'd suggest going with CSS instead of the `bgcolor` attribute. The same approach can be taken as above:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
    $style = '';
    if ($i < $achieved) {
        // give it a red background color
        $style = ' style="td-acheived"';
    }

    echo "<td" . $style . "></td>";
}
```

And then you could have the style:

```
<style>
    .td-acheived {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do this by combining it with css with the following change to your php

```
$target = 20;
$achieved = 13;
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
echo "<td class='bgcolor-".$achieved."'></td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

then in your css file

```
.bgcolor-13{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand well but i'll try.

```
$target = 20;
$achieved = 13;
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++){
if($i<=$archieved){
echo "<td bgcolor='red'></td>";
}else{
echo "<td></td>";
}
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```